# Call objects in a static vector c++

Tags: c++, static, game-engine

Im currently making a game engine in c++ for a school project. To update say the movable objects in the game i thought of a method involving a static vector of all movable object:

1. When a movable object is created, it adds itself to a static vector that is shared by every movable.
2. When i need to call a method (in this case updatePosition) in all movable objects i just access the static vector.

Movable.h:

```
class Movable {
private:
    static vector<Movable*> movables;
public:
    Movable();
    static vector<Movable*> getMovable();
    virtual void updatePosition() = 0;
};
```

Movable.ccp

```
#include "Movable.h"
vector<Movable*> Movable::movables;
Movable::Movable() {
    movables.push_back(this);
}

vector<Movable*> Movable::getMovable() {
    return movables;
}
```

So basically whenever a movable is created it pushes itself to the vector. I am trying to access this vector in my GameScene class like this:

```
void GameScene::updateLogic() {
    for (Movable* movable : Movable::getMovable()) {
        movable->updatePosition();
    }
}
```

My issue is that when running the game i get a segmentation fault. It looks like every movable object has a movable vector which in turn contains 2 movable objects that each has a vector containing 2 movables..... :
[Debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PVqB.png)

Which means that a movable adds itself to the vector and creates a new movable or something? So it adds itself infinitely, but unfortuneatly i cant locate what causes this error, that is why i asked here. Any help is appretiated, thanks!

EDIT: A movable is created when an object that inherits from movable is created:

```
class Tank : public Drawable, public Entity, public Movable, public Collidable {

private:
...

public:
...
    void updatePosition() override ;
};
```

and,

```
class HumanTank : public Tank {
private:
...
public:
...
};
```

These are created in the constructor of the GameScene class:

```
GameScene::GameScene(bool isAi, sf::Vector2u windowSize)  {
    sf::Vector2f tank1SpawnPoint {windowSize.x / 20, windowSize.y - windowSize.y / 8};
    HumanTank tank1 = HumanTank(tank1SpawnPoint, "tank1.png", "pipe1.png", "Tank 1", 100);
}
```

Comment: The vector being `static` means that it is shared by all objects of the class. So it is *the same* vector that is visible in all objects.

Comment: Maybe the object is moved to another memory location after the push_back. That would invalidate the pointer in the vector and explain the segfault.

Comment: @BoPersson i am aware of that, that is why i use a static vector, so that every movable object created can add itself to that vector and so that i can get it from another class.

Comment: @Binbon - You seemed to be concerned about the "infinity" of the pointers. The debugger output just comes from it going round in circles, when `movables[1]` points to the object containing `movables[1]`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There are many things that could go wrong, e.g. if you have a function `Movable createMovable(){ return Movable();}` then the pointer in your vector will be invalid.

Comment: @BoPersson okey thanks

Comment: in other words, your vector does not own the objects, so you have to take care that they are not destroyed somewhere else (in some code that you dont show here)

Comment: @tobi303 thanks you for the input, the only other code that i use a movable is when a object that inherit from that is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show here:

```
GameScene::GameScene(bool isAi, sf::Vector2u windowSize)  {
    sf::Vector2f tank1SpawnPoint {windowSize.x / 20, windowSize.y - windowSize.y / 8};
    HumanTank tank1 = HumanTank(tank1SpawnPoint, "tank1.png", "pipe1.png", "Tank 1", 100);
```

}

suggests that you assume you could create a `Movable` (in this case a `HumanTank`) somewhere and then have global access to it via the static vector. However, this is not the case. What really goes on is this:

```
GameScene::GameScene(/*...*/)  {
    sf::Vector2f tank1SpawnPoint {/*...*/};
    HumanTank tank1 = HumanTank(/*...*/);     // you create a Moveable
                                              // and remember its location
                                              // in memory 
} // <- here that object is destroyed and your pointer becomes invalid !!!
```

Instead of using a static vector of raw pointers I would suggest you to make your `GameScene` keeping a vector of smart pointers.

Comment: Thanks, didnt think of this. Declaring the tank1 in the .h file of GameScene and creating it in the initialization list of the constructor solved my problem :)